# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException Document root element "ehcache", must match DOCTYPE root "null"

Tags: wildfly, ehcache, saxparseexception

I am trying to deploy spring+cxf+maven based web service to wildfly. While deploying, Facing this exception

```
2017-06-13 03:20:18,874 INFO  [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Loading properties file from VFS resource ["/C:/xxxx/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/content/ServiceWrapper-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/ehcache-2.10.4.jar/ehcache-failsafe.xml"]
2017-06-13 03:20:18,883 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 118; Document root element "ehcache", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
2017-06-13 03:20:18,886 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 118; Document root element "ehcache", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
```

Could someone please help.

Comment: What does your ehcache-failsafe.xml look like?

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for the reply, XML is <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../config/ehcache.xsd">
 <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<defaultCache>    
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>

Comment: Maybe it was a paste problem and you should probably edit the question rather than paste it into comments, but that is invalid XML so it's tough to say. Which is maybe the issue. Look at `maxElementsInMemory="10000"`. That looks like an attribute, but it's just text data.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../config/ehcache.xsd">

    
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    
    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>

Comment: Hi James, You are right, that is paste problem. Could you please check the xml now.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess a bit here but you seem to load the ehcache configuration file as if it was a Spring configuration file. Which obviously won't work.

I can confirm that if you show us the actual code.

Comment: Hi Henri, thanks for the reply. Please let me know which code shall I show, spring configuration or the class in which ehcache jar is used.

Comment: You are not configuring Ehcache as a CacheManager anywhere? I'm interested in the spring configuration

Comment: Hi Henri, I could neither copy the spring configuration file, nor edit the question. How shall I send the file

Comment: Strange. You should be able to edit the question from as far as I know. You can also do a gist and mention it in a comment.

Comment: In spring config-<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
 xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache 
             http://www.springmodules.org/schema/cache/springmodules-ehcache.xsd">

Comment: In db-config.properties:ea.db.cache.provider.class = org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider and configured this property in spring -config file as <bean><...><prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${ea.db.show.sql}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${ea.db.cache.provider.class}</prop></prop>...<bean>